# facebook send button pops up in a weird way - how to repair it

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, facebook

I have added facebook `send` button to my page and in each drive, i have added `send` button so that one can share that drive information directly from the list with someone else.

but the problem is now, if you click on `send` the popup is opening inside the table and making the page ugly.

here is the link to my page: http://soputnik.ru/

just click send under `details` button.

how can i make it open just normally where the popup goes over other elements instead of going inside the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you assign `overflow: visible`, instead of "`auto`" to the `.tab-content` element, the page looks nicer

Answer (score 1):

Your div tab-content has overflow: auto.
I changed to inherit and it works very well here, just need to change other stufs like size of pop-up.

Css

```
.tab-content { overflow: inherit}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also do try this:

```
.fb_iframe_widget {
    position:absolute;
}
```